# How is the collapse of the wave function explained through electron atom scattering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, scattering, wavefunction-collapse

I have learned from [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/622193/232973) answer/comments that people have put much effort into understanding how scattering of electrons on atoms could explain where, for example on a screen behind a double-slit diffraction experiment, light flashes appear as a result of what is often called "wave function collapse".

Since wave function collapse (from an extended to a localized wave function) is commonly considered an indeterministic event, I would like to understand, what the treatment of electron-atom scattering could add to the picture of where or why an electron flashes on the screen.

Is there a way to explain the essential insights of these analyses in rather simple words?

Comment: "wave function reduction" is not a standard term in English -- the only operative term is collapse.

Comment: Okay, I admit that I have translated that literally from german. I'll change it.

Comment: I am definitely not a fan of that answer. In some interpretations (to which John Reenie, Lubos Motl and Zurek adhere, amongst others), the wavefunction is not absolute, but observer-dependent. The answer you link indicates that it is an absolute thing that exists.