# Does the electrons probability wave travel faster than light when it jumps from one enrgy level to other in an atom?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

What happens when an electron jumps from one energy level to other,does it travel faster than light or equal to light speed because photon speed is c so electron speed will also be c,am i right?

Comment: This somewhat different question may answer your question [Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622155/37364)

Comment: No.  First because electron "speed" is not what happens to an electron as it changes orbitals.  Second because as @mmesser314 suggests, the wave function (or in a classical view, the acceleration) does not happen instantaneously.