# Is there a hard clear division between a particle and a wave?

Tags: particle-physics, waves, photons, wave-particle-duality, quarks

My limited understand is that photons can we both or is a particle and a wave.
But they have 0 weight(?)

I found this quote today:

> "Quarks, like all elementary particles, are excitations of a quantum field. This, in and of itself, means it behaves like a wave, for basically ALL of its interactions.

But then what is a wave?

In the water, it is water being moved.
Water is a molecule. which is a particle,
which is hydrogen and oxygen atoms
which are electrons, protons and neutrons (?)
which are quarks
and 20 years ago they were preons.

When you get down to this level, what is a particle?
Do Quarks have different weights, which are directly composable
to the weight of an atom?

Or is space - time - gravity a wave that is built of Quarks, Photons and whatever else?

How does one establish if something is a particle or a wave?

Comment: If I may suggest a philosophical approach, one of Alan Watts.  The world consists entirely of prickly goo... or gooey prickles.  And some make a living encouraging you to see the gooenyess of it all.  Some only want you to see the prickles.

Comment: This may help - [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)

Comment: This may help - [Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622155/37364)

Comment: I recommend starting with electrons. Quarks are really complicated thanks to QCD being, to quote Fred Zachariasen, "And ugly disgusting mess that makes me want to vomit".

Comment: @CortAmmon  I love Alan Watts.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the example of light. Does it consist of electromagnetic waves of a certain frequency, or photons?

For visible light, there is no hard and fast division between wave-like and particle-like behavior; what you get depends on how you are measuring your system.

But for wavelengths much longer than that of visible light, the wave picture is more manifest. For wavelengths much shorter that that of visible light, the photon picture is more manifest. So whereas we talk about the energy of a gamma-ray photon, we don't talk about the energy of an AM-radio photon; similarly, we describe the AM-radio signal (but not the gamma-ray) in terms of wavelength.