# What's the difference between $ΔE_{\rm atom} = (Δn)hv$ and $ΔE_{\rm atom} = hv$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, notation, atoms, photoelectric-effect

I'm so much confused with so look-alike formulas ;

So to begin with:

**How is this**

[image]

**Different to this** *They are basically the same ΔEatom*

[image]

And last question:

**In this picture, we can use ΔEatom for any two energy states n**

[image]

**But here, they say we should use it inly for adjacent states** (*like n=1&2,etc...*)

[image]

**So can you please tell me the differences between all of these**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of your cited articles is wrong. it is not stated what $\Delta n$ is. maybe it should mean  you could have to photons going from n3 to n2 and then from n2 to n1, but usually the have not the same $\nu$
the last article tells you of the smallest occurring $\nu$, but it says the same as the other two above.

Comment: so what should i do? it's my professor book

Comment: @ElieMakdissi I think the first is OK too, there are cascades between different n,(this is the Δn ) see the answer by Dale here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667880/do-atoms-emit-and-absorb-photons-at-the-same-wavelengths

Comment: anna v- i didn't really understand how is Dale's answer related to my question, please elaborate :(

Comment: @ElieMakdissi It shows the n  energy states of the hydrogen atom, and explains that once an electron goes to a specific higher energy orbital, it can decay in many ways by going to low energy n orbitals. The graph shows it, so there are many Δn for de-excitation. look at the Paschen series, it is an example.

Comment: anna v - ah okay i'll check it up

Comment: trula - thank you for your answer :)!