# Double slit experiment

Tags: particle-physics

Engineering question: How does the electron gun shoot one electron at a time to the double slit target? How was this possible when the experiment was done 100 years ago? How is this done with photons? Is there a check to ensure only one electron/photon is arriving at the target?

Comment: This isn't really the same question, but it may help - [Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622155/37364)

Comment: In a standard transmission electron microscope there is only one electron in the column at a time. Low current, and they move fast…

Comment: see https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Comment: also this https://www.teachspin.com/two-slit

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you set the intensity of the source to a level at which it is unlikely that there is more than one electron or photon in the apparatus at a time. It doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: For photons there are single-photon sources that can truly only emit one photon at a time.

Comment: @JonCuster True, but the classic experiments didn't use them and they are not necessary.

Comment: Agreed, just pointing out that they exist.