# Copenhagen Interpretation vs Quantum Decoherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

I'm learning about Quantum Mechanics, and have a question about the Copenhagen Interpretation.  It states that the act of observation collapses the wave function.  It seems many people take this to mean that the system has a definite state only when observed by a conscious observer.

However, the decoherence principle states that the wave function can collapse due to interactions between the quantum system and the environment, without the need for an observer.  Thus, although observation causes decoherence and collapse of the wave function (because observation requires interaction), an observer is not necessary for the wave function to collapse or for the system to have a definite state.

What confuses me is why it seems the general understanding of QM is that an observer IS required for quantum systems to have a definite state, and this is often presented as one of the central paradoxes of QM.  According to the decoherence principle this is not true; while observation causes collapse, it can also happen without an observer, thus there is no paradox regarding QM requiring a conscious observer.

Comment: The title should be about the measurement problem.

Comment: You will have a hard time finding a formal definition of "collapse of the wavefunction". It's not a well defined term and it serves absolutely no purpose in physics. A single quantum mechanical system is not in a well defined state before a measurement. Only the ensemble of the system can be assigned a superposition of states but the outcome of a measurement depends even then on our particular choice of measurement system. The only "confusion" there is in QM is caused by attempts to trivialize these experimental facts.

Comment: Related to the comment above - [Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622155/37364)

Comment: @FlatterMann > *"A single quantum mechanical system is not in a well defined state before a measurement."* According to orthodox quantum theory, the word state is used for ray in the Hilbert space - a class of functions $\psi$ differing by a phase factor $e^{i \alpha}$ - and system is always in some definite state.

Comment: @JánLalinský Hilbert space is a mathematical abstraction. It only exists in our minds and on paper. It is simply not possible to make an infinite number of completely independent copies of a system. This is in no way different from a probability distribution. The only "things" that exist in reality in a well defined way are frequencies of outcomes and estimates for scattering coefficients. I can, on a good day, tell if an atom is in an excited state or not because I put the energy in or I took it out. In general I can't even tell that.

Comment: @FlatterMann The system is always in definite state in orthodox quantum theory.

Comment: @JánLalinský I can't tell what that is supposed to mean. I can't tell that even in classical probability theory. Which of the six possible outcome states are dice in that I have just thrown into the air and that are still moving? In reality moving dice are in no well defined state at all. Only dice resting on the table (i.e. after they have lost their kinetic energy) are in a well defined state. This situation only gets worse in QM because now what "resting on the table" means is defined by the particular measurement that we are performing, which we can chose dynamically.

Comment: > *"I can't tell what that is supposed to mean."* You should read standard textbooks on quantum theory then. It means, in orthodox quantum theory, that $\psi$ describes everything there is to say about the system.

Comment: > *"In reality moving dice are in no well defined state at all."* That is not how physics describes things. In classical mechanics, dice state is nine numbers - position, momentum and angular momentum. Similarly in quantum theory, state is always definite. The difference in quantum theory is that state alone does not determine the result of a measurement.

Comment: @JánLalinský I have never seen a QM textbook that can tell us the state of a single quantum system without measurement. QM is an ensemble theory. It can only give us statistical averages of the behavior of an infinite number of independent copies of a system. That the wave function describes the single system is the principle error behind MWI. You are correct about dice: their dynamics requires a much larger number of parameters than 1-6. That's the reason why it can not be described with their projection in the space of their resting state. For QM no such extended description exists.

Comment: @FlatterMann Quantum state is either assumed as initial condition or calculated as a result of previous state, similarly to classical state. Telling state without measurement is not a reasonable requirement. Orthodox quantum theory working with quantum state is about single system; extending it to ensembles or statistical description of many similar systems requires more assumptions about probabilities, and is typically done in terms of density matrix.

Comment: @MajorChipHazard > *"it seems the general understanding of QM is that an observer IS required for quantum systems to have a definite state, and this is often presented as one of the central paradoxes of QM"* Can you give some examples? This is not how orthodox quantum theory works. Quantum state is always definite (its description may have some gauge degree of freedom). Observer is not needed, the Born rule gives probabilities of results of measurement, which can be done automatically, without animal observers.

Comment: @JánLalinský That's the point: the free, unmeasured quantum system does not have a known physical state. The theory can not tell us what it is because nature won't tell us what it is. QM is not like classical mechanics. Classical mechanics is the consequence of QM systems under continuous weak measurement. The only reason why we know a classical state at all times is because we can measure it at all times. That is simply not possible for QM systems. As soon as we have made a measurement on such a system it is destroyed. We have either taken the energy it had out or we put more energy in.

Comment: @FlatterMann that's not generally true. We do know how to evolve quantum state in time in between measurements.

Comment: @JánLalinský I run a beam of silver atoms through a Stern-Gerlach. The beam splits in two beams,  each with a different spin state. I take a second Stern-Gerlach that is rotated by 90 degrees and apply it to one of the two beams. It splits, again. Ooops. What just happened?

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed no paradox regarding QM requiring a conscious observer. It's just that the Copenhagen interpretation is the simplest one to have as a starting point when learning QM, while understanding decoherence generally requires one to already be reasonably familiar with the theory.

I should point out, however, that decoherence is not an interpretation of QM, it is a physical phenomenon that produces measurable effects, as anyone in the field of quantum computing will certainly tell you. Decoherence itself does not solve the "measurement problem", although it helps in making the whole discussion more precise. Attempts to solve the measurement problem via decoherence alone must overcome the fact that, while decoherence tells you why the system seems to collapse to the eigenstates of the measured operator, it does not determine the probabibilities of collapsing to each one. In other words, it does not explain Born's rule. There are interesting attempts to derive Born's rule from decoherence, by means of the idea of "Envariance". I recommend watching Zurek's talk "The Quantum Theory of the Classical":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Sn63t3BeMc&

or reading his paper with the same title. There is also another very well written pedagogical paper that explains decoherence, as well as it's relation to the measurement discussion. Reading it may help in understanding what decoherence alone can and can't do with respect to this problem:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04101

Comment: > *it does not determine to which one it collapses. In other words, it does not explain Born's rule.* But explanation of Born's rule need not determine which one state is the result of the collapse. Born's rule is about probabilities of measuring all possible eigenvalues. So explaining Born's rule means explaining why probability is calculated in the way it is in Born's rule.

Comment: What you probably mean is the projection postulate: that after a measurement of a quantity results in a definite value, the new state is obtained from the old state via projection of the old state on the subspace which is consistent with the measured value.

Comment: Yes, by "explaining to which state it collapses" I meant explaining the probabilities, so Born's rule itself. I'll edit the answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You have some misconceptions that are very common in the physics community. The state of physics education about basic quantum interpretations is just abhorrent.

First of all, there is no such thing as a universally understood Copenhagen interpretation. You can try to argue with 10 adherents of it, and get about 4 different versions.

In the version you have received, it seems to be the case that **consciousness** plays a rôle, and really, that is an incredibly rare version of Copenhagen. Most people would not have had that, not least because of the theological implications that seems to have, and the usual distaste of mixing that into science. It definitely does not help that those who do believe consciousness has something to do with quantum interpretations, exit Copenhagen by themselves and subscribe instead to Consciousness Collapse = von Neumann–Wigner interpretation, which is always a rare viewpoint.

It is more common that people accept that experimental equipment alone can collapse the wavefunction in Copenhagen interpretation. This is the dominant view in Copenhagen because cloud chamber tracks show lines, and this is taken as evidence that measurement equipment alone should be able to collapse the wavefunction.

If you are interested in looking at decoherence, it is quite important to realise that you should not be using Copenhagen language. In particular, you should not speak of collapse of the wavefunction. The whole point of discussing decoherence is that Copenhagen gives a physically unsatisfactory insistence on the nature of measurement, namely that **we must never ask what measurement does**, only assert that it collapses the quantum system's wavefunction in a non-unitary-evolution kind of way.

Instead, decoherence is attempting to make a better understanding of what quantum theory itself says that measurement should be doing. First of all, it is no longer the instantaenous random collapse that Copenhagen insists it to be, but rather you get a smooth transition from pure states that are not the eigenstates of the measurement apparatus, into entangled pure states between the object and measurement apparatus and environment. **Partial trace of the environment *alone*** is sufficient to lead to the kind of wavefunctions we actually get from the measurement postulate that we all use in quantum theory. The only thing that is missing is that decoherence does not explain Born rule.

That is, **either** you postulate collapse, **or** you postulate Born rule on top of decoherence. Try not to mix the two together.

Part of the reason why decoherence is getting more and more accepted in the community is not just that we have more and more simulation evidence that it really does make for a better explanation of the process of measurement, but also that it is much more sensible in theory and better agreement with experiment. I am referring to the theory in the sense of Wigner's Friend thought experiment, that your measurement apparatus is also a quantum system that thus can be put into quantum superposition. This is also experimentally testable—with better and better control over the noise in a big quantum system, we are getting more and more able to put larger and larger systems into quantum superpositions, and also being able to control them. So, we can put a measurement apparatus into the detected-entanglement states, and then reverse the entanglement, so that it seems as if the detection did not happen.

That is, unless you really believe consciousness is somehow special, the lack of an upper bound at which a macroscopic system ceases to exhibit quantum behaviour (by this I mean GRW style, or more widely, Objective Collapse interpretations), forces us to treat human brains, which are also made of quantum material, as potentially able to be put into quantum superpositions.

As a sidenote, after the decoherence process and the universe wavefunction is now composed of separated branches, that the density operator is now filled with Born probabilities $p_i$ in $$\rho=\sum_ip_i\left|s_i\right>\!\left<s_i\right|$$further manipulations of the system need to act relative to each branch separately. In particular, one needs to use conditional probability $P(A|B)=P(A\cup B)/P(B)$, and then the decoherence + Born rule result will be equivalent to collapse postulate. Needless to say, this is incredibly important because, obviously, the correct behaviour of quantum theory predictions must be independent of the particular interpretation chosen, in order for the interpretations to even be acceptable as a contender for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is to assume that 'observation' means there must be an observer. An observation is an interaction between the quantum mechanical body being observed an a collection of other quantum mechanical particles that form the measuring apparatus- there is no need for a human being to be involved at all. In that sense, the measuring apparatus is part of the environment with which the observed body interacts, so conceptually there is no conflict between Copenhagen and decoherence interpretations. The Copenhagen interpretation effectively treats the interaction between the observed body and the measuring device as a 'black box' interaction, with an abrupt change between the before and after states of the wave functions associated with the observed body, while while decoherence interpretations are looking at how the transition from the 'before' state to the 'after' state actually comes about.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that decoherence provides some understanding about the measurement problem. You are also correct that you do not need in principle any consciouceness mechanism. **Though there is a part that decoherence does not explain regarding the measurement problem, and this is where some people think that consciouceness plays a role.**

I do a quick summary of decoherence and at the end I discuss where the consciouceness aspect could play a role according to some people.

In what follows, I assume you know what a density matrix is (but I could easily edit the answer so that such knowledge is not necessary).

The whole story behind decoherence is to consider that the quantum system $S$ you want to measure is not "alone in the universe", as there is also the measurement apparatus $A$ that will measure it (technically we also need to model the environment around the apparatus in some cases, but I won't go in this details here).

During a measurement, $S$ and $A$ will get entangled and this entanglement will enforce $S$ to become a mixed-state in some basis, i.e. quantum coherences will be killed.

I call $\{|s_l\rangle\}_l, \{|a_l \rangle\}_l$ to be orthonormal bases for $S$ and $A$.

I assume $|\psi_S\rangle = \sum_{l} s_l |s_l\rangle$ is the initial state of the system to be measured, and $|a_0\rangle$ the initial state of the apparatus. The interaction with the apparatus will transform the state of $SA$ in some state:

$$ \sum_{l} s_l |s_l\rangle \otimes |a_0 \rangle \to  \sum_{l} s_l |s_l\rangle \otimes |a_l \rangle$$

Tracing out the apparatus, we realize that the system is now a (classical) mixture:

$$\rho_S = \sum_l |s_l|^2 |s_l \rangle \langle s_l |$$

What decoherence tells you is how coherences are killed by the apparatus (or environment more generally), and in which basis these coherences are killed (what are the possible classical states you will observe).

**However** on the conceptual level, for decoherence theory, the full state is still supposed to be entangled after this interaction. It does not tell you what "breaks" this entanglement. Related to this fact, decoherence tells you nothing about which outcome you will actually observe: there is still some probability to get one or the other. Finally, even though the evolution I described is continuous in time (unitary evolution), the moment you will observe one outcome (say $|s_k\rangle$) still needs an "instantaneous collapse" that does:

$$\sum_l |s_l|^2 |s_l \rangle \langle s_l | \to |s_k \rangle \langle s_k| $$

Hence, we see that we lack some mecanism allowing to understand the full problem. What some people believe is that this mecanism could be related to consciouceness (although it is by far not the only thing that could explain it, their opinion is **very highly** debatable). Such people consider that to break the entanglement or to take the specific outcome you observe, you need some consciouceness mechanism.

Comment: Entanglement doesn't get us all the way to measurement. It gets us, at most, within a time scale separation argument from measurement. The physical definition of "measurement" requires an interaction between the quantum system and the measurement system that leaves an irreversible change in the measurement system (a "record"). That this "interaction" also has to transfer a finite amount of energy follows trivially from the third law of thermodynamics if we require that the measurement record has to be distinguishable from thermal noise.

Comment: @FlatterMann I am not sure to get your point. The fact there is irreversibility cannot be understood with decoherence which is based on unitary evolutions alone (more precisely any irreversible behavior will only occur if you decide to ignore the quantum correlations between system, apparatus and environment: the full dynamics is fully reversible). Also you are talking about temperature which means you are using extra assumptions in your comment (I am not considering any thermal bath here).

Comment: You might want to ignore FlatterMann. He has been going around everywhere polluting with his particular take. It is one thing to be an expert in experimental physics, and another thing to be incredibly ignorant and close-minded about theoretical physics and insisting upon one particular viewpoint when experts are keeping the options open.

Comment: Your last bit about the "instantaneous collapse" is actually just wrong, which is a sad defect on a rather nice answer. What you are supposed to do is to look at the particular outcome branch of the wavefunction, and then you will get the same result as the collapse postulate, that, relative to the particular outcome branch, the effective wavefunction is the collapsed one.

Comment: That was my point. Decoherence only gets us to a time scale separation argument. We can get a reversible energy transfer between the quantum (QS) system and the entangled measurement apparatus (EMA). No matter how large we make the EMA, there is always a time in the future at which the QS and the EMA will go back to their original states under unitary evolution. A true measurement needs true irreversibility. Thankfully we get that for free from relativity and the fact that spacetime is an infinite size system. In a true measurement the QS stays forever entangled with the  entire universe.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The entire talk about collapsed wave functions is completely unphysical nonsense. A wave function has the same ontological meaning as a probability distribution: it's the description of an infinite number of independent copies of a system. It doesn't change whatsoever just because we do something to one copy.

Comment: @FlatterMann, I will simply not be entertaining too much more of your comments on such matters. You do not even attempt to understand that it is your own beloved Copenhagen interpretation that made us all talk about collapsing of wavefunctions, a notion that I share with you a distaste for. As long as you treat your unexamined choice of interpretation as the sacred religion that you love it to be, there is not much meaningful discussion to be had.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Copenhagen simply says that measurements on a single system are not predictable (that's an experimental fact), that the free ensemble behaves according to a quantization procedure like the SE and that measurements on the ensemble are probability distributions that behave according to the Born rule. The entire wave function collapse thing is merely a complete misunderstanding of one unfortunate sentence in an old Heisenberg or Bohr paper. I can't even remember which one it is, it's that unimportant and inaccurate.

Comment: Go and argue about Copenhagen v.s. collapse with all the universities, not here on PSE. Here, MIT #5 https://web.mit.edu/8.05/handouts/jaffe1.pdf Texas also #5 https://personal.utdallas.edu/~son051000/chem3322/postulates.pdf Chemistry https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/The_Live_Textbook_of_Physical_Chemistry_(Peverati)/23%3A_Postulates_of_Quantum_Mechanics/23.04%3A_Postulate_4-_Expectation_Values_and_Collapse_of_the_Wavefunction Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I don't know where you would ever need "collapse". I have never used it in my entire life. I always knew what I was measuring (single quanta of energy with either a photomultiplier of one of many other types of detectors) and then I would make probability distributions out of many such measurements according to the Born rule. Nothing in my experiments ever "collapsed". They were always irreversible energy transfers from a quantum field to an external system that we usually call "the detector".