# Is there a conceptual formulation that will provide an intuitive understanding of the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, models

I am trying to find a means of conceptually understanding the double slit experiment intuitively. I understand that the actual reality of what happens may be different, but is there a formulation that can act as a reliable model for what happens?

For example picturing a photon as a wave of energy that expands out from the point of emission until some part of it interacts with matter, at which point it collapses back into a point of energy centered on the point of absorption. Would this provide a consistent model of the double slit experiment?

Comment: If you find quantum mechanics confusing, you are on the right track. Here are a couple posts where I explain as best I can. Hope it helps. [Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622155/37364). [How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540485/37364)